# Close File with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that open several files in one folder and copy one sheet to a Main File... 
Here is a part of my code

```
x = 1
While x <= UBound(openfiles)
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=openfiles(x)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=crntfile.Sheets(crntfile.Sheets.Count)

    x = x + 1
Wend
```

After the `Sheets("Sheet1").Copy` i would like to close the file `x` before looping to `x+1`.
I tried with `Workbooks(x).Close  SaveFiles:= False` but it closes instead my main file `crntfile` and not the file `x`

Thx for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to get a handle on that opened workbook while opening it. To do that create a workbook variable and set it to the opened workbook.

Also notice I specifically referenced that workbook when copying (`openedWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy`) this is because the fact that you opened a new file means it is not the active file and when you just use `Sheets` (or `range` or `cells` or many object referenced) without explicitly declaring from which parent object this child comes Excel uses the Active parent object. Sometime this is wrong. It is best to explicitly declare where you are referencing things from so there are no surprises.

```
Dim openedWorkbook As Workbook
x = 1
While x <= UBound(openfiles)
    Set openedWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=openfiles(x))
    openedWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=crntfile.Sheets(crntfile.Sheets.Count)
    openedWorkbook.Close SaveFiles:=False

    x = x + 1
Wend
```

Comment: +1 for recommending to use a workbook object variable. Though not really necessary in this case (since the opened file is typically the `ActiveWorkbook` (unless an event handler in that file opens add'l workbooks...), it is good practice, and I've found that explicitly declaring the object variables makes the code a lot easier to read and revise.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do:

`Workbooks(openfiles(x)).Close`

The way you ave it right now is opening `Workbooks(x)`, where `x` is an index of the `Workbooks` Collection object. `Workbooks(x)` is NOT the same as the file you have opened within that loop.